# Create custom method for list of custom type

Tags: apex

I followed the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm) on how to create my own custom sort function for my type that is a list. It works great. I'd like to add more customization by creating my own function that adds the field of each record in the list to a total, but only if the record has a specific status.

```
global class OpportunityWrapper implements Comparable {

    public Opportunity oppy;

    // Constructor
    public OpportunityWrapper(Opportunity op) {
        oppy = op;
    }

    // Compare opportunities based on the opportunity amount.
    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        // Cast argument to OpportunityWrapper
        OpportunityWrapper compareToOppy = (OpportunityWrapper)compareTo;

        // The return value of 0 indicates that both elements are equal.
        Integer returnValue = 0;
        if (oppy.Amount > compareToOppy.oppy.Amount) {
            // Set return value to a positive value.
            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (oppy.Amount < compareToOppy.oppy.Amount) {
            // Set return value to a negative value.
            returnValue = -1;
        }

        return returnValue;       
    }

    global Integer getTotal() {
       Integer theTotal;

       return theTotal;
    }
}
```

It would work like so, only totaling records that have a Status of Closed:

```
Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity(Status = 'Closed', Qty = 2);
Opportunity opp2 = new Opportunity(Status = 'Open', Qty = 4);
Opportunity opp3 = new Opportunity(Status = 'Closed', Qty = 6);

List<OpportunityWrapper> oppList = new List<OpportunityWrapper> {new OpportunityWrapper(opp1), new OpportunityWrapper(opp2), new OpportunityWrapper(opp3)};

oppList.getTotal(); // returns 8
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't directly do something like this in Apex. Instead, you'd just write a normal method that calls each item individually:

```
Decimal totalQty = 0;
for(Opportunity opp: oppList) {
  if(opp.Status == 'Closed") {
    totalQty += opp.Qty;
  }
}
```

It's not too bad to write, but trying to make a generic function/interface would probably be more trouble than its worth unless you plan on using it frequently.

Comment: I was hoping that wouldn't be the answer :( I'm already two for loops deep in my current code. Adding that 3rd for loop makes me afraid I'll hit cpu limits. What I'm asking is common in other languages though, right?

Comment: @TylerZika I don't think it'd be "inside" the second loop, but hard to tell without seeing the code. Usually a way to keep loops at 2 or less (or at least, in small enough values it shouldn't matter). Give the short amount of code involved, maybe just write a unit test to confirm to yourself that it performs within limits. Unit tests don't always have to be for code going to production, it can be used just to satisfy curiosity.

Comment: @TylerZika And languages like Java and JavaScript do have methods like this, but that's only because they have a host of methods like Array.reduce, Array.map, etc.